Ab initio calculation of optical line strengths
30 years ago, I made my Ph.D. (mostly) by fitting crystal field parameters (read: radial integrals) to observed transitions in the optical spectra of lanthanid compounds (mostly organometallics, with high crystal fields, complicating things). Judd-Ofelt theory was a buzzword even then, but when I asked my prof whether it might be possible to ab initio calculate the observed line strengths, he was very pessimistic.
30 years later, computers and methods heavily advanced. Randomly googled paper on the area
Even Judd-Ofelt still has free parameters, thus: Can you now relatively accurately predict at least the optical line strengths of gaseous Ln3+ ions, even better Ln3+ ions in relatively strong crystal fields, without any free parameters involved, by doing a quantum chemical ab initio calculation?
(The above paper names Füchtbauer-Ladenburg and reciprocity method, but I never heard of that before and don't know whether they use free parameters.)
